# Evaluate the summation of $(-1)^k$ from $k=0$ to $k=n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k$$

I know that the answer will be either -1 or 0 depending on whether there are an odd or an even number of sums in total, but how can I determine this if $k$ goes to infinity (which I am thinking means there is neither an even nor odd amount of sums).

How would I determine this?

Comment: The series does not converge: when $n$ goes to infinity, the sum does not "go" to anything, at least not in the usual sense of limits.

Comment: The partial sums oscillate between $-1$ and $0$ , as you said. so the limit does not exist.

Comment: The series $\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k$ is divergent: it has no defined value.

Comment: Since you're starting with $k=0$ and $(-1)^0=1$, the sum will oscillate between $1$ and $0$, not $-1$ and $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^n
&=\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{1-(-1)}\\
&=\frac{1+(-1)^n}2\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the sum does not converge to a limit. However, if we consider the [Cesàro Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) of this series, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^ns_k
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1+(-1)^k}2\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\left(\frac n2-\frac{1-(-1)^n}4\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using various summation methods you can arrive at $1/2$ being the regularized sum at infinity.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k = {1 \over 2} (1+(-1)^{n})$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Using the general form derived as:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} x^{k} = \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x}
\end{align} 
then for $x = -1$ the result becomes
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} = \frac{1 + (-1)^{n}}{2}.$$